# Story about a stranded astronaut that needed 40-something identical parts to fix his engine

Tags: story-identification

A stranded astronaut needs 40-something identical parts to fix his engine, but the machine that was able to produce these parts out of nothing was so intelligent that it saw no point in repeating itself 40 times. He ended up using all sorts of suitable materials, then spent time convincing it that repetition is good. Finally he asked the machine to make another machine that would produce one part and yet another machine until he got what he needed.

Comment: duplicate target more accurately describes plot point and has accepted answer

Answer (score 35):

This is Robert Sheckley, the story is called The Necessary Thing (unfortunately, it has no dedicated article in the English Wikipedia, see [his short story bibliography on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley_short_stories_bibliography)). It is one of his brilliant humor sci-fi stories about AAA, an interplanetary agency founded by Gregor and Arnold, two friends that often get into difficult and ridiculous situations.

It can be read in [Galaxy Magazine on Archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1955-06/Galaxy_1955_06#page/n55/mode/2up).

Comment: Thank you Andre! Knowing the title, I've located the story here https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1955-06/Galaxy_1955_06#page/n55/mode/2up

Comment: @Sergei Hey, glad we could help you find your story! I noticed you seem to have lost access to the account you used to ask the question; please consider [following these instructions to merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), so that you can **accept** this answer, thus marking the question as solved and giving a little extra thank-you to the answerer. Thanks! :-)